# Server Error ReferenceError: getComputedStyle is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, package, frontend

I'm starting to build a real-time chat application with next js. I'd want to use the (stream-chat-react) package.

So here is the **errors**:

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: getComputedStyle is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
Chat
file:///home/yahia/yahia/web/Next%20js/nextjs-live-chat/node_modules/stream-chat-react/dist/index.cjs.js (12837:24)
renderWithHooks
file:///home/yahia/yahia/web/Next%20js/nextjs-live-chat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5658:16)
renderIndeterminateComponent
file:///home/yahia/yahia/web/Next%20js/nextjs-live-chat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5731:15)
renderElement
file:///home/yahia/yahia/web/Next%20js/nextjs-live-chat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5946:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///home/yahia/yahia/web/Next%20js/nextjs-live-chat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///home/yahia/yahia/web/Next%20js/nextjs-live-chat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///home/yahia/yahia/web/Next%20js/nextjs-live-chat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderChildrenArray
file:///home/yahia/yahia/web/Next%20js/nextjs-live-chat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6211:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///home/yahia/yahia/web/Next%20js/nextjs-live-chat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6141:7)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///home/yahia/yahia/web/Next%20js/nextjs-live-chat/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
```

I'm not sure if the problem is caused by the package or by anything else.!!?

This is my code **index.js:**

```
  import React from "react";
  //! packages
  import Pusher from "pusher-js";
  import { StreamChat } from "stream-chat";
  import { Chat } from "stream-chat-react";
  import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
  //! components
  import ChannelListContainer from "../components/ChannelListContainer";
  import ChannelContainer from "../components/ChannelContainer";

 //* for setup our chat we need an API key,
 const apiKey = process.env.CHAT_API_KEY;
 //* for this chat to work we need to create an instance of stream chat
 const client = StreamChat.getInstance(apiKey);

 export default function Home() {
    return (
     <div className="app__container">
       <h2>Developer Chat App</h2>
       <Chat client={client} theme="team light">
        <ChannelListContainer />
        <ChannelContainer />
       </Chat>
    </div>
  );
 }
```

this is ***ChannelContainer.js*** file:

```
import React from "react";

const ChannelContainer = () => {
  return <div>ChannelContainer</div>;
};

export default ChannelContainer;
```

this is ***ChannelListContainer.js*** file:

```
import React from "react";

const ChannelListContainer = () => {
  return <div>ChannelListContainer</div>;
};

export default ChannelListContainer;
```

Comment: Same problem did you find any solution ?

Comment: @MikeVictoria  Hello mike, honestly No, I'm closed  the project